# Is there a way for creating methods with set type parameters and return value?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am creating a module for handling Express routes. I have created a program, which calls methods from classes in directory.

Example of that class can be seen here.

```
class UsersController {
  private ping(_: any, response: Response) {
    response.status(200).send({ message: "Pong!" });
  }

  public get(): RouteDeclaration[] {
    return [{ path: "/ping", method: "get", action: this.ping }];
  }
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to, e.g extend the class with some abstract class, which could allow me do something like an all method's wildcard:

```
abstract class RouteController {
  abstract get(): RouteDeclaration[];
  abstract *(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void; // like this!
}
```

Is it possible to somehow wildcard these methods with no specific name after all?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N9Jr1m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it with an index signature like this:

```
type Method = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;

abstract class RouteController {
  abstract get(): RouteDeclaration[];

  [key: string]: Method;
}

class UserController extends RouteController {
  private ping(_: any, response: Response) {
    response.status(200).send({ message: "Pong!" });
  }

  get() {
    return [{ path: "/ping", method: "get", action: this.ping }];
  }

  myMethod: Method = (req, res, next) => {
    // implementation
  };

  otherMethod: Method = (req, res, next) => {
    // implementation
  };

  // this will give a compiler error:
  illegalMethod(v: number): string {
    return "";
  }
}
```

I expected the compiler to automatically infer the arguments and return types for the methods in the `UserController` class, but that only seems to work for simple types. That's why it seems best to extract the signature to something like `Method` and use that for the method implementations. Of course you can also just make them real methods, but you will have to specify the types for the arguments and return type for each method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Abstract methods should have a method signature, which implies on having a method name, to be implemented.

I suggest you to create a generic method name like `execute`.